# I cannot create a table in Bigquery due to schema issue

Tags: database, google-bigquery

I am having difficulty with a creating table in Bigquery.

The table I tried to upload looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLbCH.png)

First, I tried auto-detect but it didn't work.
And error message is like this:

Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM' as TIMESTAMP for field SleepDay (position 1) starting at location 65 with message 'Invalid time zone: AM'

So, I tried Edit as text like this:
Id:INTEGER, SleepDay:DATETIME, TotalSleepRecords:INTEGER, TotalMinutesAsleep: INTEGER, TotalTimeInBed: INTEGER

And now I see error like this:
Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse 'Id' as INT64 for field Id (position 0) starting at location 0 with message 'Unable to parse'

Isn't the Id like 1503960366 integer?
How should I change this?

Answer (score 1):

> Could not parse 'Id' as INT64 for field Id (position 0) starting at
> location 0 with message 'Unable to parse'

This error message reads to me as you are trying to read in the header ('Id') as an int, too. There is an option to skip one or more header row(s) under "Advanced options" when adding a table to BigQuery, try adding the number 1 there to skip the top row.

Comment: Thanks, but now I am seeing this: Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM' as DATETIME for field SleepDay (position 1) starting at location 65 with message 'Invalid datetime string "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM"'

Comment: Isn't "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM" DATETIME?

Comment: I just designated "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM" as string and succeeded in uploading the table.